# How to find the minimum set of (n) attributes frequently repeated in an m:n relations

Tags: sql, statistics

I have two table: USERS (IDUser, UserDesc) and ROLES (IDRole, RoleDesc) with an m:n relation  stored in an associative table RolePerUser (IDUser, IDRole).

I would like to group these roles in a more manageable PROFILE, and I need a way to discover what roles can compone a PROFILE, basing the analysis on the frequency of repetition.

For Example:

```
USER1  has (Role 1, Role 3, Role 4, Role 5, Role 6)
USER2  has (Role 1, Role 4, Role 5, Role 6, Role 7)
USER3  has (Role 1, Role 4, Role 5, Role 7, Role 8)
```

- an hypotetic PROFILE1 (n=3) can be built upon Role 1, Role 4, Role 5 with
  the coverage of 100% of users
- another PROFILE2 (n=4) can be built upon Role 1, Role 4, Role 5 and Role 6 with the coverage of 66% of users

I would like to write a SQL query that can put in evidence the eligible relations, after fixing a parameter (n) representing the numbers of ROLES in PROFILE

Is there a way (statistic formula, or other tricks) to accomplish this task? The dataset are quite large (576 roles against 11.069 users, with an average of 20 roles per user)

Thank you in advance

Paolo

EDIT: I am using MSSQL 2008 R2

Comment: Please edit your question and include the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set number, then you can use aggregation to get what you want.  The structure of the query is:

```
select ru1.idrole, ru2.idrole, ru3.idrole, ru4.idrole, count(*)
from RolePerUser ru1 join
     RolePerUser ru2
     on ru1.iduser = ru2.iduser and ru1.idrole < ru2.idrole join
     RolePerUser ru3
     on ru2.iduser = ru3.iduser and ru2.idrole < ru3.idrole join
     RolePerUser ru3
     on ru3.iduser = ru4.iduser and ru3.idrole < ru4.idrole
group by ru1.idrole, ru2.idrole, ru3.idrole, ru4.idrole
order by count(*) desc;
```

This is standard SQL and it should work in all databases.

For performance, you want an index on `RolePerUser(iduser, idrole)`.  Then try the query on two roles, three roles, and so on, to see if the performance is acceptable.